# removing water from your boxing bag base

Tags: equipment

I have a free free-standing bag with the water water-filled base.
I planning to move in a month to a different location.
What's the best way to take out the water from the base?
Do I need a pump or there is a better way?

Note: The bag is indoors and in a room that is 30 feet away from the shower room.

The internet is full of instructions on how to fill it up, but how to get it out is nowhere to be found.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: How high is the base? If the water level is high enough, you might be able to use this technique to get some of it out. Then it'll be easier to carry it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJSrgykg0mA

Comment: I know this trick, but unfortunately, it is inapplicable, as the base is not high enough.
And it is super heavy to carry.

Thanks a lot for your ideas. 
I decided to go with the water pump options, seems this is the best way, I just ordered it from Amazon.
Thanks again for trying to help

Comment: I think the instructions are printed on the bottom of the base.

Answer (score 5):

There's a type of vacuum cleaner that can suck both dust and water, commonly called "shop vac". Looks like a big bucket on wheels. Very useful for DIY stuff, sawdust, sanding drywall, and sucking water out of a toilet when you want to replace it without making a mess. If you can get or borrow one, it'll solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas. Vaccum is a good idea as well, will keep it in mind for the future.
I decided to go with the water pump options, seems this is the best way, I just ordered it from Amazon.
Thanks again, man.

Answer (score 4):

Slide it into the shower and turn it over to drain it. If you can't budge it, then you may need someone to help you.

You can buy some moving pads to help, also. Like these, which I would only use on carpet:

[https://www.amazon.com/Furniture-Carpeted-Surfaces-Suitable-Sliders/dp/B0757HTDG2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0757HTDG2)

Or if you have wood or tile flooring, you can just put a towel under it and use that to help slide it.

If you need to lift it up over the outside edge of the shower or bathtub, and it's too heavy, think about shoving books or something under it one by one to raise it up a little at a time until it can be pushed over the edge of the shower or tub.

A pump would work also. There are water pumps you can buy. They don't cost a lot. You would just have a pot next to it and fill the pot up, then dump, then return for more.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas, Steve. 
I decided to go with the water pump options, seems this is the best way, I just ordered it from Amazon.
Thanks again, it definitely helped.

Answer (score 1):

Place it on a pile of wood (eg, several squares of stacked plywood) as high as you can get it, no more than a foot.  Then siphon the water out into a bucket.  Use several buckets so that when emptying one, the other is filling.

Total equipment is plastic tubbing 3' long from a fish pet store, 2 buckets or wash basins, and something to hold the unit 8" to 12" up off the floor.

You can (and should, if available) use a staircase instead, so rather than lifting the unit, you lower the bucket.